# xgboost.train versus XGBClassifier

Tags: python, scikit-learn, xgboost

I am using python to fit an xgboost model incrementally (chunk by chunk). I came across a solution that uses xgboost.train but I do not know what to do with the Booster object that it returns. For instance, the XGBClassifier has options like fit, predict, predict_proba etc.

Here is what happens inside the for loop that I am reading in the data little by little:

```
dtrain=xgb.DMatrix(X_train, label=y)
param = {'max_depth':2, 'eta':1, 'silent':1, 'objective':'binary:logistic'}
modelXG=xgb.train(param,dtrain,xgb_model='xgbmodel')
modelXG.save_model("xgbmodel")
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`XGBClassifier` is a `scikit-learn` compatible class which can be used in conjunction with other scikit-learn utilities.

Other than that, its just a wrapper over the `xgb.train`, in which you dont need to supply advanced objects like `Booster` etc.

Just send your data to `fit()`, `predict()` etc and internally it will be converted to appropriate objects automatically.

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I did and it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not entirely sure what was your question. `xgb.XGBMClassifier.fit()` under the hood calls `xgb.train()` so it is a matter of matching us arguments of relevant functions.

If you are interested how to implement the learning that you have in mind, then you can do

```
clf = xgb.XGBClassifier(**params)
clf.fit(X, y, xgb_model=your_model)
```

See the [documentation here](http://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html#xgboost.XGBClassifier.fit). On each iteration you will have to save the booster using something like `clf.get_booster().save_model(xxx)`.

PS I hope you do learning in mini-batches, i.e. chunks and not literally line-by-line, i.e. example-by-example, as that would result in performance drop due to writing/reading the model each time

Comment: Thank you for your comment. By the way, I am considering what you just said and I am minimizing the number of times that I am reading data from hard-disk. I read in the data in huge chunks and then divide it even further internally.

Comment: @Max That makes sense and speeds up the training. The only question out of my curiosity: if you read in large volumes in memory anyway, why do you want/need to divide them into smaller chunks for training? One does that (training in mini-batches) often for NN training but I was not aware that it is also done for GBMs